# Why is using git with && failing when inside a .sh but not from the command line?

Tags: shell-script, git, dash

I have a script (called `update_content.sh`) that is supposed to run 3 consecutive `git` commands and the first version looked like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
git fetch --all && git reset --hard && git merge
```

When I run it I see this output:

```
web@bane:~# ./update_content.sh
Fetching origin
error: unable to create file locales/fr.json (File exists)
error: unable to create file locales/it.json (File exists)
fatal: Could not reset index file to revision 'HEAD'.
```

However when I changed it to this:

```
#!/bin/sh
git fetch --all
git reset --hard
git merge
```

And run it I see this:

```
web@bane:~# ./update_content.sh
Fetching origin
HEAD is now at 5859b2e Added Business tab
Already up-to-date.
```

The newline approach gets the result I want however it does not have the "don't proceed if a step failed" quality of the `&&`.  Is there something about how `git` works that makes it incompatible with the `&&` or am I missing something about `&&`?

I did a little more digging and found that the one liner with `&&` when run from the command line doesn't throw errors but also doesn't actually reset the local working copy, however the new line approach inside a script (and run one at a time) does.

Comment: Run `bash -x update_content.sh` and post the output. Also, try the script with newlines plus a new line just below `#!/bin/sh` containing `set -ex`.

Answer (score 1):

Usually I would guess that one of the first two commands exits with a non-zero code. But that would prevent all the following commands to be run, and non-run commands cannot generate error messages...

However, you can check the exit code of the commands with this:

```
git fetch --all   ; echo "exit code: ${?}"
git reset --hard  ; echo "exit code: ${?}"
git merge         ; echo "exit code: ${?}"
```

And it would help to run the script through

```
bash -vx ./update_content.sh
```

Comment: @Jason Sperske using error codes in your scripts will make it so much easier to debug them, always use return codes. I thank return codes everyday of my life, for without them, I will be completely clueless.